# LaunchScreen.storyboard can’t replace image

Tags: ios

Why Changing launchImage so troublesome?

My app used a .storyboard for a Launch Screen.Now, I need to replace a new picture for the launchScreen. First of all, I put the picture into 'Image.xcassets', the launchScreen is white.

Then I search some ways to solve it .

1. Delete the app and restart. This can change the launchImage, but this method is not good for the users.
2. Put the picture in the root directory. In a few days the launchScreen does load the new image. but maybe 2 or more days later, launchScreen become white or black.

Has anyone ever experienced this, what advice? thanks for any help.

Comment: When you open launchScreen storyboard do you see the image there or no? If you dont see it in the storyboard you either did not name the image properly and it cant find it or your imageview is not visible...

Answer (score 0):

These caches are used by Springboard to make app switching fast. This isn't a problem that will affect your production users and should in theory go away the next time Springboard decides to snapshot your app.

That being said, this isn't a problem you can fix. This is a bug in Apple's code not yours.